# How do I add modulus to this? (hours:minutes:seconds)

Tags: c++, time, format, modulus

This is my first time on this site, and as such, the format of this question may be wrong in some ways.  That being said, here is the exercise I am struggling with.
"Write a C++ program that prompts the user to input the elapsed time for an event in seconds.  The program then outputs the elapsed time in hours, minutes, and seconds.  (For example, if the elapsed time is 9630 seconds, then the output is 2:40:30.)"
Here is what I have programmed so far in Code::Blocks-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int seconds;
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds1;
cout << "How long did the event take in seconds?" << endl;
cin >> seconds;

hours= seconds/3600;
minutes= %(seconds/3600);
seconds1= %(seconds/minutes);
cout << "The event took"<<hours<<":"<<minutes<<":"<<seconds1<<"." << endl;
cout << endl;

return 0;

}
```

My main question is how I would add the modulus operation to this program.  I know I need to include it, as there is a clear remainder after variable: hour, and minute.

Also, two error codes appear when this program is run through the compiler:

> Line 16) error: expected primary-expression before '%' token
>
> Line 17) error: expected primary-expression before '%' token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
minutes= %(seconds/3600);
```

the syntax for the mod, % operator in an assignment is

```
minutes = value1 % value2;
```

You have no left-hand argument, here value1, in your expression.

The seconds1 part is straightforward, you just take the seconds mod 60.

```
seconds1 = seconds % 60;
```

The minutes part you'll have to think about a little. You can do it in two ways.

1. You need to subtract the number of seconds already accounted for by the hours value, then divide by 60. No mod required, or rather a manual mod.
2. using mod. Get the remainder of the hours not accounted for by the hours calculation, `% 3600` then calculate the number of minutes this is.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!